# npx create-react-app does not start creating application files and folders

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npm-install, npx

I am trying to create a new react app, but the command does not run like it normally does. The cursor simply moves to the next blank line and the installation doesnot begin. I tried installing few packages from codemirror before this. The same problem goes for npm install commands as well.

(base) shubhammazumdar@Shubhams-Air FJP 9 % node -v
v18.16.0
(base) shubhammazumdar@Shubhams-Air FJP 9 % npm -v
9.5.1
(base) shubhammazumdar@Shubhams-Air FJP 9 % npx create-react-app my-app

I tried re-installing node Js as well but the problem persists.